# Stop slideshow from cycling if only has one image + stop fade of first image when slideshow loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have a slideshow that is almost perfect in fitting my needs. I just need to change a couple of things:

1. The slideshow should not fade in and out if there is only one image.
2. The slideshow should not fade in when the page is loaded.

Thanks!

I have the code here:

```
$(window).load(function() { //start after HTML, images have loaded

var InfiniteRotator = {
    init: function() {
        //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
        var initialFadeIn = 1000;

        //interval between items (in milliseconds)
        var itemInterval = 5000;

        //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
        var fadeTime = 2500;

        //count number of items
        var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

        //set current item
        var currentItem = 0;

        //show first item
        $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

        //loop through the items        
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
                currentItem = 0;
            } else {
                currentItem++;
            }
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        }, itemInterval);
    }
};

InfiniteRotator.init();

});
```

Html code:

```
<div id="rotating-item-wrapper">
<img src="images/slider/1.jpg" class="rotating-item" />
<img src="images/slider/2.jpg" class="rotating-item" />
<img src="images/slider/3.jpg" class="rotating-item" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just set a few variables? Like `var fadeTime = itemCount > 1 ? 2500 : 0;`

Comment: I just tried that this: var fadeTime = itemCount > 1 ? 2500 : 0;

Comment: Well you would need to set itemCount to the number of items that you have. You could also make the `infiniteLoop` only run if you have more than 1 item.

Comment: I can't set the number of items. It will be different depending on the user.

Comment: You could check how many items there are dynamically. Look at @Mohamed-Yousef's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slideshow should not fade in and out if there is only one image.

you can get the number of img using

```
if($('.rotating-item-wrapper .rotating-item').length > 1){
  // run slider
}else{
  // just one image don't slide
}
```

The slideshow should not fade in when the page is loaded.

you already used

```
$(window).load();
```

to make your code more easier to control .. use infiniteLoop  as a function

```
 var infiniteLoop = function() {
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
                currentItem = 0;
            } else {
                currentItem++;
            }
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

        });
```

and then setInterval

```
if($('.rotating-item-wrapper .rotating-item').length > 1){
      // run slider
      setInterval(infiniteLoop , itemInterval);
    }else{
      // just one image don't slide
    }
```

the full code looks like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() { //start after HTML, images have loaded
    var InfiniteRotator = {
        init: function() {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            var initialFadeIn = 1000;

            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            var itemInterval = 5000;

            //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
            var fadeTime = 2500;

            //count number of items
            var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

            //set current item
            var currentItem = 0;

            //show first item
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);
            if(numberOfItems > 1){
                //loop through the items        
                var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
                    $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

                    if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
                        currentItem = 0;
                    } else {
                        currentItem++;
                    }
                    $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

                }, itemInterval);
            }
        }
    }

      InfiniteRotator.init();

    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/5/)

Comment: Would you mind putting this code into the code I used. I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, but now there is not any images sliding. If I use 1, 2 or 3 images, nothing is happening.

Comment: @kimberlyvoo you checked your code? and give all the images a class .rotating-item??

Comment: @kimberlyvoo sorry syntax error in my code .. please try updated answer .. and always look to your console for any errors

Comment: I tried your code. The slideshow now does not work with multiple images. Any ideas?

Comment: @kimberlyvoo  sorry for delay but i have a bad internet connection .. anyway look at this http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/  .. something went wrong with $(window).load()

Comment: I will look at the fiddle for this. Maybe I can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @kimberlyvoo I already made a jsfiddle for you .. see it in a previous comment

Comment: Here is the update. Added css and it works now. Checking to see if your code works for only one image. I'll be back. http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/1/

Comment: It kind of works. We are getting closer. If there is only one image, I need to show it. It is a blank white page. http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/2/

Comment: @kimberlyvoo  anyway answer updated with latest one .. Good Luck

Comment: Seems like it works! I still need to try on my website, but I'm sure it will work. Thanks for all your help :) I might be back to ask about the fading in when the page loads. But it doesn't bother me that much. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: I was hoping you (anyone) could help me out with one more question. It has to do with this slideshow code, so I don't want to post a new question unless I have to. Is there any possible way to get the text to not jump up and down? I can't use position: absolute. because it messes up the rest of my website. Please look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9xn19111/7/

Comment: Thanks! That's not really going to work because the text needs to be able to dynamical go to two lines without being restricted by the height you have on the wrapper. Also, the fading seems to be choppy doing it this way.

Comment: I'm going to ask this as a new question. The comments are getting too long :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to look like this:

```
var InfiniteRotator = {
init: function() {
    //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
    var initialFadeIn = 1000;

    //interval between items (in milliseconds)
    var itemInterval = 5000;

    //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
    var fadeTime = 2500;

    //count number of items
    var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

    //set current item
    var currentItem = 0;

    //show first item

// We want the first slide without fade

    $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(0);

    //loop through the items        

//dont slide if there's no more than 1 item
if(numberOfItems < 1){
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

            if (currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
                currentItem = 0;
            } else {
                currentItem++;
            }
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);



           }, itemInterval);
}
        }
    }
```